# FirebaseStorage: Deleting a folder and all its contents using node.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I want to delete a Firebase Storage folder and all its contents using node.js / Firebase Admin SDK but I'm not able to.

A similar question was asked in the google group below about a year ago and I'm wondering if there is a solution now:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/aG7GSR7kVtw

I am able to delete a single file using node.js example below:

https://mzmuse.com/blog/how-to-upload-to-firebase-storage-in-node

But I'm not able to delete a folder and all it's contents.

Any ideas? Am I missing something?

Here's the code I'm using

```
const keyFilename="path/to/my/private.json";
const projectId = "myprojectid";
const bucketName = `${projectId}.appspot.com`;

const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({
    projectId,
    keyFilename
});
const bucket = gcs.bucket(bucketName);
```

**THIS WORKS FINE - Deleting a single file**

```
const deleteFile = 'users/user1/folder1/IMG_1.JPG'
const gcFile = bucket.file(deleteFile);
gcFile.delete((err,res)=>console.log(err||res));
```

**THIS DOES NOT WORK - Deleting the folder and contents**

```
const deleteFolder = 'users/user1/'
const gcFolder = bucket.file(deleteFolder);
gcFolder.delete((err,res)=>console.log(err||res));
```

### --

**THIS IS NOT A DUPE AS MARKED BY SOME MEMBERS**

My question is specific to node.js and the answer given is for Java.

UPDATE

I found this a page in google cloud site where they show a way to delete all files under a directory (folder)

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/google-cloud/0.56.0/storage/bucket?method=deleteFiles

```
bucket.deleteFiles({
  prefix: 'images/'
}, function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    // All files in the `images` directory have been deleted.
  }
});
```

But I'm still not able to delete the folder itself

Comment: You can't do this programmatically.  Read the answer on the dup to understand why there are not actually any "folders" in a Cloud Storage bucket.  Currently, the only way to delete all the files under a location is with the gsutil command line.

Comment: While these are Swift questions, the answers are applicable and contain really good information that answers the question: [This One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214052/delete-folder-with-contents-from-firebase-storage) and [Another One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749647/firebasestorage-how-to-delete-directory) and [This Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/aG7GSR7kVtw)

Comment: As of Jul 2019, you can list a folder, and delete its contents recursively, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749647/firebasestorage-how-to-delete-directory/56844189#56844189

Answer (score 1):

From [this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43687499/7004388)

> You can delete only the whole bucket, but you cannot delete a folder
>   in a bucket.

Use `GcsService` to delete files or folders.

String bucketName = "bucketname.appspot.com";

```
GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance());
gcsService.delete(new GcsFilename(bucketName, "test"));
```