# How do you Delete from Firebase Storage using Angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I am basically new to Angularfire2, I am trying to delete a folder from Firebase Storage when the user presses the delete button. Unfortunately, such information is not in the Angularfire2 [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md).

I have basically tried to use the code below:

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private storage: AngularFireStorage) { 
      this.clientsCollection = this.afs.collection('clients', ref => ref.orderBy('uid', 'asc'));;
  }

   deleteClient(client, callback){
    this.storage.ref(client.uid).delete();
  }
```

Unfortunately, it throws the following error

```
FirebaseStorageError {code_: "storage/object-not-found", message_: "Firebase Storage: Object '3CqyNHrIwQ3sRlj83JKM' does not exist.", serverResponse_: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 404,↵    "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object"↵  }↵}", name_: "FirebaseError"}
```

I have stored each client's documents in a folder which has the name similar to the client's *uid*. Which is really just an ID generated by Firebase. I get the above error when I try to delete that folder. Please help, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 17):

I think a better way would be to ***delete a file via its download URL***. To do that, you can simply call `storage.refFromURL(url).delete()` on the instance of the injected `AngularFireStorage` dependency.

```
...
constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) { }
...
delete(downloadUrl) {
  return this.storage.storage.refFromURL(downloadUrl).delete();
}
...
```

Comment: FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: refFromURL() expected a full URL but got a child path, use ref() instead. (storage/invalid-argument)

Getting this error somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Even if it's not in the documentation, you are using the right way to delete files using AngularFireStorage. I use it myself, and you can check it in [source files](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/storage/).

Seems like your `client.uid` is not refering to any resource.

But even if it was, you're saying that "when I try to delete that folder" but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749647/firebasestorage-how-to-delete-directory) **you cannot delete folders**, you will have to keep list of files.

Answer (score 3):

You can list all items inside the folder then delete them one by one, empty folder will be removed automatically!

```js
let folderPath = 'path/to/folder';

this.storage.storage.ref(folderPath).listAll().then(data => {
  data.items.forEach(item => {
    this.storage.storage.ref(item['location']['path']).delete()
  });
})
```

Comment: this.storage.storage.ref(folderPath).listAll().then(data => {
  data.items.forEach(item => {
    item.delete()
  });
})

Comment: Thanks. this helped. although item.delete(); also suffice to delete.

Answer (score 1):

The following is working on `Angular v15` and `AngularFire v7.5.0`

```
  //remove all request files
  removeRequestFiles(requestId: string) {
    const folderPath = `requests/${requestId}`;
    const folderRef = this.storage.ref(folderPath);

    folderRef.listAll().subscribe((list: ListResult) => {
      list.items.forEach((fileRef: Reference) => fileRef.delete());
    });
  }
```