# How to delete an folder from Firebase which contains images?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am deleting single image by using its storage reference which is working fine. But when I try to delete an entire folder of images, it is not deleting.

My code is:

```
StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("FormImages");

storageRef.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Log.d("LOG", "Images are Deleted.");
                            }
                        });
```

I want to delete entire folder from Firebase Storage. How could I achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37757909/10826159), it's impossible. You have to delete them one by one.

Comment: Why its impossible?

Comment: As of Jul 2019, you can list a folder, and delete its contents recursively, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749647/firebasestorage-how-to-delete-directory/56844189#56844189